# Join SQL without Unique Identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables:

Table A:

| EmployeeID | DailyHour | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID001 | 2 | 2021-02-01 |
| ID001 | 4 | 2021-02-03 |
| ID001 | 4 | 2021-02-04 |
| ID001 | 4 | 2021-02-10 |
| ID001 | 8 | 2021-02-15 |
| ID002 | 8 | 2021-02-20 |

Table B:

| EmployeeID | Week | StandardHours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID001 | 2021-02-05 | 40 |
| ID001 | 2021-02-12 | 40 |
| ID001 | 2021-02-19 | 40 |
| ID002 | 2021-02-12 | 40 |

How can I get the sum of `DailyHour, StandardHours` per `EmployeeID` (`Date` within range of `Week`)

Expected Output:
For `EmployeeID` = `ID001` and `Date` Between `Feb 1 2021` and `Feb 12 2021`

| EmployeeID | DailyHours | StandardHours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID001 | 14 | 80 |

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Aggregate separately in subqueries/CTEs first, then `JOIN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to aggregate first, and *then* `JOIN` the data, based on the Employee's ID:

```sql
WITH Daily AS(
    SELECT EmployeeID,
           SUM(DailyHour) AS DailyHours
    FROM dbo.TableA
    WHERE [Date] >= '20200201'
      AND [Date] <= '20200212'
    GROUP BY EmployeeID),
Standard AS(
    SELECT EmployeeID,
           SUM(StandardHours) AS StandardHours
    FROM dbo.TableB
    WHERE [Week] >= '20200201'
      AND [Week] <= '20200212'
    GROUP BY EmployeeID)
SELECT D.EmployeeID,
       D.DailyHours,
       S.StandardHours
FROM Daily D
     JOIN Standard S ON D.EmployeeID = S.EmployeeID;
```

If an Employee might not have Standard or Daily hours, you'll need to use a `LEFT JOIN` or `FULL OUTER JOIN`, along with `ISNULL` (in the `SELECT`).

Answer (score 2):

This becomes tricky if an employee is not in both tables.  This gives you two options, one of which is using `full join` and aggregation before the join -- and becomes tricky for filtering to a particular employee or date range.

Another is `union all` and aggregation:

```
select employeeid, sum(dailyhour), sum(standardhours)
from ((select employeeid, date, dailyhour, null as standardhours
       from a
      ) union all
      (select employeeid, date, null as dailyhour, 
       from b
      )
     ) ab
where employeeid = 'ID001' and
      date >= '2021-02-01' and
      date <= '2021-02-12'
group by employeeid;
```